# Using endIconMode in a TextInputLayout the end icon is enabled (the visible icon) by default

Tags: android, kotlin, passwords

I'm building a password field using TextInputLayout in Android (Kotlin) and when I use the endIconMode attribute the icon in the end is enabled (more to say it shows the visible eye icon) and whenever I click on it for the password to be visible, on the end it shows the visibility off icon even though the password is visible. How can I solve this?
This is my XML code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_field"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/password"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="#1AC4C4C4"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="20dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="20dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_field_stroke"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="0.5dp"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields

Comment: this is what I have used and it didn't work. Either way I found a solution for it

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found for it is that you should make an endIconDrawable as a custom one and custom it this way:

```
**password_icon.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibile" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off"/>
</selector>
```

and add it this way on the TestInputLayout:

```
app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/password_icon"
```

Comment: This worked for me, remember though to also set `app:endIconMode="password_toggle"` on the TextInputLayout.